# Create a git alias to display a specific file from the last commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to create a `git` alias to do a `less` style display of a specific file from the last commit?

The usual command for that would be `git show HEAD~0:FileName`.

However creating an alias like this `sh-la = show HEAD~0:` and running it with `git sh-la FileName` does not work.

Comment: Why the `-1`? I made sure there were lots of `git` questions here before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you would need the filename concatenated directly after 
`HEAD~0:`. With a simple alias that's not what happens with extra arguments. In your example this will be executed:

```
git show HEAD~0: FileName
```

Notice the space after `HEAD~0:`.

To achieve what you want, you need use a function, like this:

```
sh-la = "!f() { git show HEAD~0:\"$1\"; }; f"
```

Comment: I see. Thanks very much, your function alias works perfectly. I had no idea that `git` aliases beginning with a `!` call an external command, what a useful feature.